# com/sun/deploy/util/WinRegistry throws ClassNotFoundException Intellij Idea

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, jar, registry

I try to read a value from Windows Registry. This code works good, when I run it in Intellij Idea.

```java
public static String getInstallLocationValue() {
    String value = WinRegistry.getString(
            WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            "SOFTWARE\\" + ApplicationConstants.APP_NAME + "\\",
            "InstallLocation");
    System.out.println("Windows Distribution = " + value);
    return value;
}
```

But it crashes when I run it from jar file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/deploy/util/WinRegistry at com.doos.utils.RegistryManager.getInstallLocationValue(RegistryManager.java:10) at com.doos.core.Main.main(Main.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.deploy.util.WinRegistry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Do you have any ideas, how to fix this?

Comment: Found a part-solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java/6163701#6163701)

Comment: Better helps [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) Advapi32Util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not solve the problem with **WinRegistry**, instead I used the **Advapi32Util** class from the [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) library.